# fromJson(myString, MyObject.class) doesn't populate every field of MyObject

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

at the end of this method, some fields in the moviesInfoList object are null. The most crucial fields to me are in the List < Result > in MoviesNowPlaying object. The fields adult, id, overview, popularity, title and video are populated, but the others are null. I don't understand why some fields get populated and others don't.

```
private void processMoviesInfo(String infoString){

    this.moviesInfoList = new MoviesNowPlaying();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    this.moviesInfoList = gson.fromJson(infoString, MoviesNowPlaying.class);
}
```

Here's the JSon and my objects:

```
{
"dates": {
    "minimum": "2015-08-05",
    "maximum": "2015-09-16"
},
"page": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/lyVlbE8iRIdGBUwhq79EziqHSBW.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            878
        ],
        "id": 166424,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Fantastic Four",
        "overview": "Four young outsiders teleport to a dangerous universe, which alters their physical form in shocking ways. Their lives irrevocably upended, the team must learn to harness their daunting new abilities and work together to save Earth from a former friend turned enemy. [20th Century Fox]",
        "release_date": "2015-08-07",
        "poster_path": "/g23cs30dCMiG4ldaoVNP1ucjs6.jpg",
        "popularity": 15.832627,
        "title": "Fantastic Four",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 4.7,
        "vote_count": 406
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/57xvgxE5EUMnEVY9BV6lIx9jnip.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            80,
            53
        ],
        "id": 249070,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Hitman: Agent 47",
        "overview": "An assassin teams up with a woman to help her find her father and uncover the mysteries of her ancestry.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-21",
        "poster_path": "/4VmZeT8YkuMI6BrA623mHZDISlN.jpg",
        "popularity": 14.9903,
        "title": "Hitman: Agent 47",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 5.9,
        "vote_count": 151
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/mQwpjcFzQpZOZWqyyNKsdhjDCxF.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            18,
            10402
        ],
        "id": 277216,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Straight Outta Compton",
        "overview": "In 1987, five young men, using brutally honest rhymes and hardcore beats, put their frustration and anger about life in the most dangerous place in America into the most powerful weapon they had: their music. Taking us back to where it all began, Straight Outta Compton tells the true story of how these cultural rebels-armed only with their lyrics, swagger, bravado and raw talent-stood up to the authorities that meant to keep them down and formed the world's most dangerous group, N.W.A. And as they spoke the truth that no one had before and exposed life in the hood, their voice ignited a social revolution that is still reverberating today. Straight Outta Compton stars O’Shea Jackson Jr., Corey Hawkins and Jason Mitchell as Ice Cube, Dr. Dre and Eazy-E, and is directed by F. Gary Gray.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-14",
        "poster_path": null,
        "popularity": 8.502256,
        "title": "Straight Outta Compton",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8.2,
        "vote_count": 170
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/qOFJRNGSKceFAJYyVzRc6FviWFX.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            53,
            28,
            80
        ],
        "id": 287948,
        "original_language": "fr",
        "original_title": "The Transporter Refuelled",
        "overview": "The fast-paced action movie is again set in the criminal underworld in France, where Frank Martin (Skrein) is known as The Transporter, because he is the best driver and mercenary money can buy. In this installment, he meets Anna (Chabanol) and they attempt to take down a group of ruthless Russian human traffickers who also have kidnapped Frank’s father.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-04",
        "poster_path": "/ux8d25AymGE0NajHVRXBARyp0xX.jpg",
        "popularity": 8.180596,
        "title": "The Transporter Refuelled",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 4.8,
        "vote_count": 46
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/A0bFdUMtd4mcXMRou7alzk6HQVZ.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            35,
            28,
            12
        ],
        "id": 203801,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Man from U.N.C.L.E.",
        "overview": "In the early 1960s, CIA agent Napoleon Solo and KGB operative Illya Kuryakin participate in a joint mission against a mysterious criminal organization, which is working to proliferate nuclear weapons.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-14",
        "poster_path": "/5ttOaThDVmTpV8iragbrhdfxEep.jpg",
        "popularity": 5.609048,
        "title": "The Man from U.N.C.L.E.",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.7,
        "vote_count": 228
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/9T9GPRD4ptt3HdH6KbxRtzmCIZ2.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            99
        ],
        "id": 324308,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine",
        "overview": "When Steve Jobs died the world wept. But what accounted for the grief of millions of people who didn’t know him? This evocative film navigates Jobs' path from a small house in the suburbs, to zen temples in Japan, to the CEO's office of the world's richest company, exploring how Jobs’ life and work shaped our relationship with the computer. The Man in the Machine is a provocative and sometimes startling re-evaluation of the legacy of an icon.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-04",
        "poster_path": "/3c5TZijlxhLK9ABf5CpJq08S3JX.jpg",
        "popularity": 4.228574,
        "title": "Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 5.5,
        "vote_count": 20
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/3lsHjySMtaDQ6KFi9UvEkoIFCwp.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            80,
            53
        ],
        "id": 276907,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Legend",
        "overview": "Tom Hardy will play twins Ronnie and Reggie Kray, who have worked their way through the ranks to become powerful crimelords in London's underworld in the 1960s.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/3tD0r8F6b7vygxZt3iRvf2ELwAO.jpg",
        "popularity": 4.354825,
        "title": "Legend",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6,
        "vote_count": 8
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "genre_ids": [
            35
        ],
        "id": 329263,
        "original_language": "de",
        "original_title": "Fack ju Göhte 2",
        "overview": null,
        "release_date": "2015-09-10",
        "poster_path": "/bOIqoQ9AiScfmmiQ1P2sZyuIfbZ.jpg",
        "popularity": 4.253851,
        "title": "F*ck You, Goethe 2",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 5.9,
        "vote_count": 8
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/nRhKISIQg738WJj4fN8yKhO08Uw.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            27,
            35
        ],
        "id": 298312,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Visit",
        "overview": "The terrifying story of a brother and sister who are sent to their grandparents' remote Pennsylvania farm for a weeklong trip. Once the children discover that the elderly couple is involved in something deeply disturbing, they see their chances of getting back home are growing smaller every day.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/msWELvigxn6rkKAUPgnllFsH99F.jpg",
        "popularity": 4.078126,
        "title": "The Visit",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 3.9,
        "vote_count": 10
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/jdGHRopcOEPDRQVfvuIv4BkxUgw.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            12,
            16,
            35,
            10751
        ],
        "id": 263109,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Shaun the Sheep Movie",
        "overview": "When Shaun decides to take the day off and have some fun, he gets a little more action than he bargained for. A mix up with the Farmer, a caravan and a very steep hill lead them all to the Big City and it's up to Shaun and the flock to return everyone safely to the green grass of home.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-05",
        "poster_path": "/aOHsNN1p2nuiF9WaMaCNXy0T80J.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.066908,
        "title": "Shaun the Sheep Movie",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7,
        "vote_count": 132
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/2sm4iVFwA3KDvz7FO150VtoNQBE.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            53
        ],
        "id": 304372,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Perfect Guy",
        "overview": "Leah Vaughn appears to have the ideal life. She enjoys a challenging, fast-paced career as a lobbyist; Dave, her longterm boyfriend loves her. And yet, at 36, she's ready to move to the next phase. Marriage and a family seem a logical and welcome step. Dave is not so sure. A bit commitment phobic, his misgivings lead to a painful break up.  Enter Carter Duncan, a handsome, charming stranger whose path keeps crossing with Leah's. Caring and solicitous of Leah and her family and friends, their relationship rapidly progresses. It seems Leah has met the perfect guy. But if it seems too good to be true... Soon Carter's protective nature morphs into something more sinister. It's clear Leah has to end this new relationship and when she does, her onetime lover becomes her ultimate enemy. It will take every bit of her cunning and resolve to escape and outwit him.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/iiumlMSYHfskEDsXVfhXXxr9pfd.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.045578,
        "title": "The Perfect Guy",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 2.8,
        "vote_count": 10
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "genre_ids": [],
        "id": 359122,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Strawberry",
        "overview": "Strawberry is upcoming 2015 tamil horror film directed and produced by Pa. Vijay.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": null,
        "popularity": 4,
        "title": "Strawberry",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "genre_ids": [],
        "id": 358994,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Ex With Benefits",
        "overview": "Even after their break-up, a couple can't get enough of each other.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/75qFR4VwjJKrHT66WjhoJasWe2M.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.9589,
        "title": "Ex With Benefits",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/2RvClRhC9kNUbLCKluwiKc6mVzN.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            35
        ],
        "id": 288036,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Sleeping with Other People",
        "overview": "A good-natured womanizer and a serial cheater form a platonic relationship that helps reform them in ways, while a mutual attraction sets in.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/vcJh2q1tSJoSz4u1wDdXquW5Z4w.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.917532,
        "title": "Sleeping with Other People",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 0.9,
        "vote_count": 4
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "genre_ids": [],
        "id": 358996,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Hero",
        "overview": "The daughter of a police chief and a son of the streets go to great lengths to prove their intense love is the real deal.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-11",
        "poster_path": "/zRWhkEcWeLD1o1aBEUEkcmfEeIs.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.88555,
        "title": "Hero",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/ggT0PgdPW8DZdGA09WBC6J8xfUB.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            35
        ],
        "id": 357974,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Student Bodies",
        "overview": "After experiencing a series of sexually related mishaps, a high school adds sexual education to its curriculum to rehabilitate the student body, and hires Laci Cox to teach it - the only catch is Laci is a virgin.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-03",
        "poster_path": "/afz7olJxMAVFv6sRUvksV1lr2Oa.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.743345,
        "title": "Student Bodies",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.5,
        "vote_count": 3
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/mbA7SCtJoFTactP1lDHA055qCf.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            35
        ],
        "id": 261392,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "American Ultra",
        "overview": "A stoner and his girlfriend's sleepy, small-town existence is disrupted when his past comes back to haunt him in the form of a government operation set to wipe him out.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-21",
        "poster_path": "/6oGHH27nqaLGfpcgYRIZYSJs7AD.jpg",
        "popularity": 2.616011,
        "title": "American Ultra",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 5.3,
        "vote_count": 98
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/yU0v8xNqMeCOTo4exyxsNp7N7Kw.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            80,
            18
        ],
        "id": 261023,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Black Mass",
        "overview": "The true story of Whitey Bulger, the brother of a state senator and the most infamous violent criminal in the history of South Boston, who became an FBI informant to take down a Mafia family invading his turf.",
        "release_date": "2015-09-04",
        "poster_path": "/yIVnNriiyl522hk3LFLJrrMovhP.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.511516,
        "title": "Black Mass",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 2.4,
        "vote_count": 34
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "genre_ids": [
            27
        ],
        "id": 358962,
        "original_language": "ru",
        "original_title": "Пиковая дама: Черный обряд",
        "overview": null,
        "release_date": "2015-09-10",
        "poster_path": "/ahyihVSeCwHqdNXPEogDj99pREf.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.5046,
        "title": "Пиковая дама: Черный обряд",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/pidYWYCxEniELXXwLeqPoL175Kl.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            53,
            878,
            18
        ],
        "id": 193687,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Z for Zachariah",
        "overview": "A psychological thriller about a girl who believes she is the only survivor after a devastating nuclear event, but comes to learn she is not alone.",
        "release_date": "2015-08-13",
        "poster_path": "/csm8I8cERdRlV7182TeMr8B3QKA.jpg",
        "popularity": 3.425515,
        "title": "Z for Zachariah",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 4.8,
        "vote_count": 25
    }
],
"total_pages": 36,
"total_results": 705
```

}

```
public class MoviesNowPlaying {

private Dates dates;
private Integer page;
private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
private Integer totalPages;
private Integer totalResults;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//getters and setters...


public class Dates {

private String minimum;
private String maximum;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//getters and setters...

public class Result {

private Boolean adult;
private Object backdropPath;
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Integer id;
private String originalLanguage;
private String originalTitle;
private String overview;
private String releaseDate;
private Object posterPath;
private Double popularity;
private String title;
private Boolean video;
private Double voteAverage;
private Integer voteCount;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//getters and setters
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all! That was it, working now.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSON isn't all magic; it does need some help from you.

In this case, the fields in your Java class don't match the names of the JSON properties, and thus GSON does not know how the two should map.

For example, your `Result` class has an `originalLanguage` field, but the JSON has an `original_language` field.

There are a few easy fixes for this:

1. Rename your Java fields to match the JSON
2. Use the `@SerializedName` annotation to annotate your Java fields with the correct JSON field names. For example, the following will fix your `originalLanguage` issue:

   ```
   @SerializedName("original_language")
   private String originalLanguage;
   ```
3. Apply a [`FieldNamingPolicy`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html) to your GSON object. Specifically, it looks as though you want the [`LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES) policy, since your JSON properties are in snake_case and your Java fields are in camelCase. For example:

   ```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
       .create();
   ```

Comment: there is a simpler way, though. see https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html

Comment: @njzk2 That's true if one of the global policies applies, though there are often edge cases. I'll add it to my answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Some of your names for your objects like genreIds do not match your json object names. For things like that, you're going to want to either match the name exactly or above the field declaration put a `@SerializedName("genre_ids")` tag.

like

```
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```